# N-ary relations of sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

[image]

How can I solve n-ary relations, is there a formula or something.I solved the first one but how can I solve more complicated than just with two, like the one in example $(d)$

> EDIT:
>   The problem is correct this way:
>
> a. Give an explict subset of A for the given set.
>   b. Give an explict subset of $A^2$ for the given relation.
>   c. Give an explict subset of $A^3$ for the given relation.
>   d. Give an explict subset of $A^4$ for the given relation.

Comment: An n-ary relation is a set of n-tuples.  What was your answer for a?

Comment: For the option a I think it's straightforward, I only have to find the pairs that match the condition. But for the third and fourth example should I find all the pairs and see if they meet the condition  also but that looks like a lot of work, so is there an easier way to solve these.

Comment: Did you copy the problem correctly?  It looks bogus.

Comment: Now that you have the correct statement (though the length of the tuples are swapped between b and c), where are you stuck?  For a, just list the members less than or equal to $2$.  For b, list the triples that satisfy the requirement, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is incorrect.  The correct problem is:
a. Give an explict subset of A for the given set.
b. Give an explict subset of $A^2$ for the given relation.
c. Give an explict subset of $A^3$ for the given relation.
d. Give an explict subset of $A^4$ for the given relation.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. The problem was given that way, but I guess your paraphrasing is better, I'm going to edit my question.

Comment: It is more than just better.  It is correct! @nor

Comment: Ok good. Still I don't understand how to solve them.

Comment: b asks for triples and c asks for pairs

Comment: Do I have to find them all, by writing them one by one? Or is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: Yes, one by one 'til you're done.  The easy way is to outsource, to bribe or con somebody into doing it.

Answer (score 0):

For c, $A^2$ is the set of ordered pairs with elements from $A$.  One of them is $(1,5)$ and that one satisfies the requirement.  Another is $(4,4)$, which does not.  You are expected to list all the pairs that satisfy the requirement.  You should find $15$ of them. b seems like a lot of work because there are $216$ triplets in $A^3$ and most of them will satisfy the requirement.